# Import a query from Access into Excel based on an adjustable input

Tags: vba, excel

I want to import a query from Access to an Excel Spreadsheet. I would like the code to be adjustable sp that on sheet 1 in cell B9 I can type the name of the query as it appears in Access. So anytime I want to import a new query I just have to change the name in B9. My current VBA hardcodes the name of the query and I am not sure how to change this. This is what I have so far which imports the specific query listed.

Sub GetQuery()

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Long
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Set dbs = DBEngine.OpenDatabase("C:\Desktop\DataProject\Database.accdb")
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("Query One")
Set wsh = Worksheets("Sheet1")
For i = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
    wsh.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rst.Fields(i).Name
Next
wsh.Range("A1").Resize(ColumnSize:=rst.Fields.Count).Font.Bold = True
wsh.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
dbs.Close
Set dbs = Nothing
```

End Sub

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not sure if this is really useful, but maybe you can adap it to your needs:

```
Option Explicit
Dim ValueB9 As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Value = "" Or ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Value = ValueB9 _
    Or Left(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Formula, 1) <> "=" Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandle:
    ValueB9 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Value
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    Set dbs = DBEngine.OpenDatabase("C:\Desktop\DataProject\Database.accdb")
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(ValueB9)
    Set wsh = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For i = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
        wsh.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rst.Fields(i).Name
    Next
    wsh.Range("A1").Resize(ColumnSize:=rst.Fields.Count).Font.Bold = True
    wsh.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    dbs.Close
    Set dbs = Nothing

End If

Exit Sub

ErrorHandle:
If Err.Number = 3078 Then
    MsgBox "Query name is wrong"
Else
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error number " & Err.Number
End If
End Sub
```

This code will trigger every time you input the name of your query in cell B9 in Sheet1. You have to input the name in the cell like this:

```
="YOUR QUERY NAME"
```

If you don't type it like a formula, (for example, if you just type the name of the query) it won't trigger. If you type wrong the query name, it will throw error.

Try to adapt it to your needs.